# Gridview thinks it has only one column but I can seem more

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a stored proc that returns 6 columns.

I have it set as the datasource for my GridView.

I have an automatically generated Select button.

I only see the select button and two columns

In the SelectedIndexChanged event, I only show 1 column:

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int 
            iCols = GridView1.Columns.Count;
        Console.WriteLine(iCols);
    }
```

The gridview is not null as I'm showing one row.

Comment: your markup from your aspx page please.

Answer (score 1):

I turned to Dino Esposito's book, "Programming Microsoft ASP.NET 4 and saw that auto-generated columns are always "zero" columns. Since I auto-generated a select button, that made one column. I instead used manually produced fields. Problem solved.

Comment: In general, it's usually better to explicitly define all the GridView columns you intend to display, rather than relying on ASP to figure it out for you. It also gives you much more control of how each column is rendered (width, color, etc.).